# Unable to Check Internet connectivity

Tags: java

Hi all I'm using a piece of java code to detect whether internet is available or not

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnect;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Object objData = urlConnect.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if (e.getMessage().contains("Server returned HTTP response code")) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Let me tell you the exact set up .
I'm having a desktop(IP : 16.0.0.69 ) with proxy(16.0.0.203) internet connection. `isInternetAvailable()` is working if i give the below parameters to JVM

```
-Dhttp.proxyPort=3333 -Dhttp.proxyHost=16.0.0.203
```

Now when I try to execute the same function on proxy server(16.0.0.203)itself it is not working 
below are the ipconfig details of proxy server

IPv4 Address  16.0.0.203

Subnet Mask  255.255.255.0

IPv4 Address 172.18.20.34

Subnet Mask  255.255.0.0

Default Gateway  172.18.0.200

I checked my internet options to see whether my proxy server (16.0.0.203) is using any proxy or not and it is not using any proxy.
In addition to that proxy server is running with cyberoam -Corporate Client  .
For proxy functionality I have installed CCproxy.

Whats wrong with above code and what i have to configure

Comment: I think it was not an Java Error. Your code works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Proxy server has direct connection to the internet.

So you should remove the proxy settings in the jvm when running the code on the proxy server itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I removed that line and now i turned of the Firewall as well still not working